# How to list the available android sdk packages for (automated) installation via commandline

Tags: android, command-line, sdk, automation

I want to install android sdk components via commandline.

How can I list them and install them in commandline (for automation)?

Answer (score 1):

The available packages and the names can be get with this command:

```
android list sdk -u -s -e -a

-u = no ui
-s = silent
-e = extended details on each package
-a = all packages
```

Then you get an output like this:

```
id: 1 or "tools"
 Type: Tool
 Desc: Android SDK Tools, revision 25.2.4
```

so the id "tools" can be used for example.

I used this command to install:

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-support,tools,platform-tools,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-usb_driver,build-tools-25.0.2"
```

echo y answers the license question.